# What is the last line spoken in Texas Chainsaw Massacre

Tags: analysis, dialogue, texas-chainsaw-3d

In the 2013 new release Texas Chainsaw Massacre 3D, the last line in the film is spoken by Heather as she takes the food upstairs from Jed and locks the door.  I couldn't make out what she said, and it's kind of crucial to the plot as I don't know if she chose to stay with him or not.  Does anyone know what it was?

Comment: It's the grandmother saying from the letter "now it's your turn"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what she says, but in the post credits scene, her adoptive parents come to visit. As they knock on the door, her "mother" tells her "father" to say he loves Heather. He replies by saying that for that kind of money, he almost does. Then they hear a weird noise as Leather-face opens the door wielding a chainsaw at them. So basically she does stay with him. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's actually the grandmother saying it in the letter and yeah, it says, "Now it's your time."

Comment: This is the correct answer. It is the grandmother speaking the line, "Now it's your time".

Answer (score 1):

i think she says "now its your time"

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late for the question and answer but I believe she is saying " And Now Its You And I. Since they are the only surviving members of their family. And she is now going to care for him

Comment: Welcome to [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com/tour). You might want to elaborate a bit more on your answer to provide additional information and differentiate it from the already provided answers